# How do I destructure a Record<string,unknown> and cast to a type at the same time?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and cannot seem to figure out how to destructure an object of type Record<string,unknown> in a single line. Below is a contrived example showing what I'm talking about.

```
class Point {
  x=0;
  y=0;
}

class Square {
  len=2;
  width=2;
}

const useObjects = (): Record<string,unknown> => {
  return { point: new Point(), square: new Square() }
}

// this works... but requires 2 lines
const {point:p } = useObjects();
const point = p as Point;

// this gives a ts error
const { point }: { point: Point } = useObjects();
```

The ts error is "Property 'point' is missing in type 'Record<string, unknown>' but required in type '{ point: Point; }'."

From what I can tell the syntax of my destructuring statement is correct, I just can't figure out what the error message is trying to tell me or how to resolve it. Could someone please explain the type error and why typescript isn't happy with my attempt at destructuring in a single line?

Or is there a better type I should be using for an object with unknown keys/values than Record<string,unknown> that would allow for a single line destructure?

Comment: Is there a reason that the return type is `Record<string,unknown>`?  If you had no return type at all and just let Typescript infer it then you would get the correct types.

Comment: In this case I was just showing a contrived example of what I was running into, I like your suggestion of allowing typescript to infer the type when possible though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell the compiler that the returned type from the function has the property `point` with the type `Point` and let the property type be defined implicitly like this:

```
const { point } = useObjects() as { point: Point };
```

But I would personally change the returned type from the function to the exact object you are actually returning like this:

```
const useObjects = (): { point: Point, square: Square } => {
  return { point: new Point(), square: new Square() }
}
const { point } = useObjects();
```

The thing is that you actually have to tell the compiler what type this point property will be or tell it what will be for certain.

Comment: When should I use the type declaration to the left of the assignment (like I had in my original post) then?

Comment: Most of the time you use when you are initializing a variable like `const p: Point = {x:2...}`, in your case the return type is implicit by the function return so there should be no need to tell the compiler two times what the value type should be